# How to minimize with BFGS in Python?

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following code in R:

```
LogLikelihood <- function(c, x, y) {
    p <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(c[1] + c[2] * x)))
    log_likelihood <- sum(log(p[y == 1])) + sum(log(1 - p[y == 0]))
    return(-log_likelihood) # minus ll because we minimize in R
}

start_params <- c(1, 1)
optim_log_regression = optim(
    start_params,
    LogLikelihood,
    x = x,
    y = y,
    method = 'BFGS'
)
```

I need an equivalent code for minimization in Python. So far, I think it might look something like this:

```
start_params = np.array([1, 1])
res = minimize(log_likelihood, start_params, method='BFGS', options={'gtol': 
               1e-6, 'disp': True})
```

How do I tell the minimize function to optimize only the argument "c" and somehow I need to provide "x" and "y". Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `args` keyword in `scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=()...`

> args : tuple, optional
>
> ```
> Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives (Jacobian, Hessian).
> ```

The objective function may take several parameters, the first one is always a scalar for one-dimensional optimization or numpy array / list if the optimization is multi-dimensional.

You can call the optimization function like

```
res = minimize(log_likelihood, start_params, args=(x, y), method='BFGS', ...
```

Comment: thanks, can u please write example code? By using args, how do I say that x and y are given and that it should minimize only c?

Comment: @MachineLearningGod Every scalar in vector x0 will be part of the minimization. So the decision which var to modify is done by x0 and fun definition, not by using args.

Comment: @Joe I don't have to provide a function for derivatives right? That is optional I see in the documentation. I want the optimizer to find the derivatives itself, I don't want to write additional function for that.

Comment: Correct. This also depends on the optimizer. Some use derivatives, some don't.